# how to get value of clicked row column of gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

this is the code of `gridview` in .aspx

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridDaysPart" runat="server" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
        GridLines="None" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="Smaller" 
        onrowcommand="GridDaysPart_RowCommand">
</asp:GridView>
```

and I am creating column in .cs file like this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sun", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Mon", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Tue", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Wed", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Thu", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Fri", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sat", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
return dt;
```

and then binding the gridview.
now I want to get the value of the particular [row][cell], on which I click, I can get the row index using rowcommand event, but how to get to know that which column is clicked ?
thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to handle the click event, do you provide a button, hyperlink or an other control that already supports a click event or do you want to use the clientside click event(e.g. on the table-cell)?

Comment: it's a simple gridview, i want to get the value on table cell click.

Comment: @TimSchmelter waiting for your answer.

Comment: http://interviews.dotnetthread.com/2009/02/making-gridview-rows-or-individual.html

Comment: really nice link, it has the answer of my question. thanks Tim

Answer (score 3):

You can  hook on [selectedindexchanged](http://dotnetspeaks.net/post/Selecting-GridView-Row-by-clicking-anywhere-on-the-row.aspx) and get value by `GridView.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text`

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var value= String.Format("You selected row {0} with {1} {2}",
                                            GridView1.SelectedIndex + 1,
                                            GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text,
                                            GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
}
```

or use

```
var value= CustomersGridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[0].Text;
```

Edit:
use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499319/asp-net-c-sharp-gridview-row-click-function)

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rownum = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    foreach(GridViewRow row in sender.Rows)
    {
        if(row.Cells[0].Text == "a-value-")
        {
             // Do something....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but for using selectedindexchanged event, i need to use select button for gridview but i can't use select button in it.i just want to click on content of gridview and get that value.

Comment: How do I call it from different buttons that I have in my row? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24453747/how-to-take-action-for-each-button-in-gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGridView.CurrentCell property

```
int columnIndex = dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
int rowIndex = dataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
```

You can refer this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void dataGridView1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].ToString();
    }
```

We Can Use This To get Value of particular Cells Clicked using The Cell Clicked Event.
I did it in C# Hope Works For Others As well.

Answer (score -2):

try to `GridView.RowEditing`:

```
String xxx = CustomersGridView.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells[0].Text;
```

review this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting%28VS.80%29.aspx)